# Google Chrome logo on Windows 8 Start Screen not showing default

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

This is a minor problem but it kind of annoys me because it used to work. When I set Google Chrome as the default browser on Windows 8 Professional 64-bit, it works as it should (with links opening in Google Chrome and everything), except Internet Explorer is coloured as the default browser.
I find it weird because it only happens with Google Chrome. When I set another browser like Firefox as the default browser it colours it as the default browser like it's supposed to.

[image]

This is IE with chrome - IE seems to be set as default yet in reality Google Chrome is

[image]

Firefox Nightly with IE

Comment: It all looks grey to me - could you add some screenshots - even if you don't have the rep to embed images directly give a link and someone will edit it in. You can screenshot the start screen by pressing the windows key and the printscreen key together, and looking in my pictures

Comment: Okay so this is what it's like when Google Chrome is the default browser: http://puu.sh/43Kfw.png
And this is what it's like when Firefox Aurora is the default browser: http://puu.sh/43Ki9.png

Notice how Google Chrome doesn't change its icon like the others do, instead Internet Explorer does.

Comment: OH. You're running the nightly. Does it do metro?

Comment: I've edited in the images - feel free to edit any of the text I added in

Comment: I tried getting the nightly to work with metro but it wouldn't work. Anyway, do you have any idea why the Chrome tile isn't changing to reflect its default status? I noticed that when I go into the chrome://settings/ page to make it the default browser, I get two Internet Explorers pop up to make default, and one of them corresponds to Chrome: http://puu.sh/43L2R.png (this is with Internet Explorer as the default, trying to change Chrome to default).
Could this be related to my problem?

Comment: I'm guessing nothing really supports metro properly, and your 'default' type icon is the metro version's icon. FF is acting odd, not chrome.

Comment: Really? I had the 'default' tile for Chrome working a week ago and now it doesn't work. The one with the Chrome logo on a black background.

Answer (score 0):

You can only register 1 default app as modern Browser so only 1 icon is shown. In your second picture the Firefox is default browser so only the Firefox Metro Tile is shown.

> The default new experience enabled desktop browser always appears as a
>   square tile. Any secondary tiles belonging to the default new
>   experience enabled desktop browser also appear with new user
>   experience tile visuals.

MS explains this here:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=243079

Comment: Yes, I know that. You don't understand. I have the Google Chrome browser set as default, yet the Internet Explorer tile is coloured as default.

Comment: the second screen shows the **desktop** IE and the metro firefox (as default browser)

Comment: I'm talking about the first screen. The second one was only to show what is the expected behaviour (which happens with all browsers EXCEPT FOR Google Chrome).

Comment: ok. File this as a bug in the Chromium bug tracker.